# Make create bamboo plugin available in deployment project

Tags: plugins, bamboo

We have created our own bamboo build plugin named "SearchReplace" and the plugin is available for selection when we create a build plan/projects. But when we try to use the same plugin within Deployment project , the plugin isn't available for selection .

We have added below category logic with atlassian-plugin.xml

```
<category name="deployment"/>
```

But still its not populating the plugin .

Have we missed a step to make it available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task class should implement CommonTaskType interface to be available for Build and Deployments, see https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/6.7.1/com/atlassian/bamboo/task/CommonTaskType.html